# C# XML --> How to get the attribute value and xpath that belongs to this attributes element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm looking for a way to walk through a XML file and get for a few attributes the text and the xpath.
But I have no idea how to do that. I know how to get all the text from the attributes I want, but the problem with that is that I cann't see the xpath where it is in.
Can some one help me?
The code =

```
       // XML settings
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;                        

        // Loop through the XML to get all text from the right attributes
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sourceFilepathTb.Text, settings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        if (reader.GetAttribute("Caption") != null)
                        {                                
                            MessageBox.Show(reader.GetAttribute("Caption"));
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test Description="Test XML" VersionFormat="123" ProtectedContentText="(Test test)">
    <Testapp>
        <TestappA>
            <A Id="0" Caption="Test 0" />
            <A Id="1" Caption="Test 1" />
            <A Id="2" Caption="Test 2" />
            <A Id="3" Caption="Test 3">
                <AA>
                    <B Id="4" Caption="Test 4" />
                </AA>
            </A>
        </TestappA>
        <AA>
            <Reason Id="5" Caption="Test 5" />
            <Reason Id="6" Caption="Test 6" />
            <Reason Id="7" Caption="Test 7" />
        </AA>
    </Testapp>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, LINQ to XML is simpler:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var captions = document.Descendants()
    .Select(arg => arg.Attribute("Caption"))
    .Where(arg => arg != null)
    .Select(arg => arg.Value)
    .ToList();
```

**[Update]**

To find XPath for each element that has Caption attribute:

```
var captions = document.Descendants()
    .Select(arg =>
        new
        {
            CaptionAttribute = arg.Attribute("Caption"),
            XPath = GetXPath(arg)
        })
    .Where(arg => arg.CaptionAttribute != null)
    .Select(arg => new { Caption = arg.CaptionAttribute.Value, arg.XPath })
    .ToList();

private static string GetXPath(XElement el)
{
    if (el.Parent == null)
        return "/" + el.Name.LocalName;

    var name = GetXPath(el.Parent) + "/" + el.Name.LocalName;

    if (el.Parent.Elements(el.Name).Count() != 1)
        return string.Format(@"{0}[{1}]", name, (el.ElementsBeforeSelf(el.Name).Count() + 1));
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but an XPath expression like `/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A/@Caption`, which your solution produces, selects not one but four `Caption` attributes. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Dimitre - you're right, I missed this part. Fixed my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start. You can workout how to prepend the leading slash.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // XML settings
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;

            // Loop through the XML to get all text from the right attributes
            using ( XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Test.xml", settings) ) {
                while ( reader.Read() ) {
                    if ( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element ) {
                        Console.Write(reader.LocalName + "/"); // <<<<----
                        if ( reader.HasAttributes ) {
                            if ( reader.GetAttribute("Caption") != null ) {
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("Caption"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Press any key ..."); Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And just BTW, I try to avoid nesting code that deeply. Too hard to read.

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT: (days later)**

I finally got some time to myself... So I sat down and did this "correctly". It turned out to be a lot harder than I first thought. IMHO, this recursive solution is still easier to groc than XSLT, which I find infinetely confusing ;-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 
{
    public class XPathGrepper : IDisposable
    {
        private XmlReader _rdr;
        private TextWriter _out;

        public XPathGrepper(string xmlFilepath, TextWriter output) {
            _rdr = CreateXmlReader(xmlFilepath);
            _out = output;
        }

        private static XmlReader CreateXmlReader(string xmlFilepath) {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;
            return XmlReader.Create(xmlFilepath, settings);
        }

        // descends through the XML, printing the xpath to each @attributeName.
        public void Attributes(string attributeName) {
            Attributes(_rdr, attributeName, "/");
        }
        // a recursive XML-tree descent, printing the xpath to each @attributeName.
        private void Attributes(XmlReader rdr, string attrName, string path) {
            // skip the containing element of the subtree (except root)
            if ( "/" != path ) 
                rdr.Read();
            // count how many times we've seen each distinct path.
            var kids = new Histogram();
            // foreach node at-this-level in the tree
            while ( rdr.Read() ) {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
                    // build the xpath-string to this element
                    string nodePath = path + _rdr.LocalName;
                    nodePath += "[" + kids.Increment(nodePath) + "]/";
                    // print the xpath to the Caption attribute of this node
                    if ( _rdr.HasAttributes && _rdr.GetAttribute(attrName) != null ) {
                        _out.WriteLine(nodePath + "@" + attrName);
                    }
                    // recursively read the subtree of this element.
                    Attributes(rdr.ReadSubtree(), attrName, nodePath);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if ( _rdr != null ) _rdr.Close();
        }

        private static void Pause() {
            Console.Write("Press enter to continue....");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using ( var grep = new XPathGrepper("Test.xml", Console.Out) ) {
                grep.Attributes("Caption");
            }
            Pause();
        }

        private class Histogram : Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            public int Increment(string key) {
                if ( base.ContainsKey(key) )
                    base[key] += 1;
                else
                    base.Add(key, 1);
                return base[key];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this program only shows the correct results if all leaf elements have a `Caption` attribute. For any leaf element that hasn't a `Caption` attribute, its corresponding XPath expression is also output.

Comment: Dimitre, you are "correct", but 6 hours late. This solution is NOT perfect (and I said so), but it was *simple* and *timely*. Sigh. I mean, what happened... the Eastern block used to understand pencils.

Comment: @corlettk: 6 hours before I saw your incorrect solution and wrote the comment I was sleeping as you probably are now. As for this solution being not perfect, *here* you are perfectly right. And do not compare the "eastern block" solution to yours -- theirs was exact and yours cut the tree below the roots. Also note that @Alex Aza quickly corrected the issue I pointed to him in contrast of you -- you do not seem to care about learning, and improving so don't overrate yourself (infinitely in this case) by comparing your wrong solution to the pencil of the Eastern block.

Comment: In addition to the first grave problem, your solution has a second one which is also serious -- the same as the one I pointed out to @Alex Aza. I am only writing this comment to warn any reader not to spend their time trying to use your "solution" -- it has two serious and difficult to solve problems.

Comment: Dimitre, We don't know enough about the ACTUAL problem (which is closely related to the USAGE of the results) to know what is an ADEQUATE solution. I looked at the OP's code and estimated his/her current level at "near beginner" (atleast in this domain), so I proposed a SIMPLE addition to OP's code which get's them part-way there, and would be part of a whole-hog solution, IF that is what is actually needed. I really DO think that throwing a COMPLEX xslt at a noob is analogous to spending millions developing a 0G biro. Correct, but (probably) inappropiate. Peace brother.

Comment: And BTW, I upvoted your solution, as the ONLY correct one at the time. I've since upvoted Alex's also... please down vote mine (I can't down vote my own solution, and it's NOT "wrong enough", IMHO, to warrant deletion), so that is all WE can do to see that the best available solution comes to the top of the pile, for future readers. Cheers mate. Keith.

Comment: @corlettk, Keith: It is absolutely right that your solution shows a viable alternative, only it is not right in some missing details. I would have downvoted it if it were completely wrong. In my opinion, the best thing you can do, brother, is to edit it and make it a complete one. Cheers, mate. Dimitre.

Comment: @Dimitri: Cool... I'll do that... it's a boring Sunday afternoon. There's nothing on the tube (if you're not into gratuitous violence or snooty-arty-farty stuff) and I can't afford to drink ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**A simple and precise XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//@Caption"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@Caption">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="path"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(': ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@Caption" mode="path">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vSiblings" select=
   "count(../*[name()=name(current())])"/>

   <xsl:if test="$vSiblings > 1">
     <xsl:value-of select="
     concat('[',
              count(preceding-sibling::*
                [name()=name(current())]) +1,
            ']'
           )"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <xsl:text>/@Caption</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Test Description="Test XML" VersionFormat="123" ProtectedContentText="(Test test)">
    <Testapp>
        <TestappA>
            <A Id="0" Caption="Test 0" />
            <A Id="1" Caption="Test 1" />
            <A Id="2" Caption="Test 2" />
            <A Id="3" Caption="Test 3">
                <AA>
                    <B Id="4" Caption="Test 4" />
                </AA>
            </A>
        </TestappA>
        <AA>
            <Reason Id="5" Caption="Test 5" />
            <Reason Id="6" Caption="Test 6" />
            <Reason Id="7" Caption="Test 7" />
        </AA>
    </Testapp>
</Test>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A[1]/@Caption: Test 0
/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A[2]/@Caption: Test 1
/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A[3]/@Caption: Test 2
/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A[4]/@Caption: Test 3
/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A[4]/AA/B/@Caption: Test 4
/Test/Testapp/AA/Reason[1]/@Caption: Test 5
/Test/Testapp/AA/Reason[2]/@Caption: Test 6
/Test/Testapp/AA/Reason[3]/@Caption: Test 7
```

**Do note**: This is the only solution presented so far, that generates the exact XPath expression for any single `Caption` attribute.

`/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A/@Caption`

**selects 4 attribute nodes, whereas**:

`/Test/Testapp/TestappA/A[2]/@Caption`

**selects just a single attribute node ans is what really is wanted**.